# Footer and header do not get resized and get overlapped when i make browser smaller

Tags: html, css

Im having this issue with the Login page where header and footer do not get resized when i make a browser window a bit smaller:

```
body {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        background: #FBFCFE;
        font-family: Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #2B2B2B;
        display: flex;
        min-height: 100vh;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
.loginPage {
    max-height: 1150px;
}
.loginPageHeader {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #517084;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 125px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.loginPageSignInForm {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 40%;
    left: 41%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
}
#loginPageFooter {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    background: #517084;
    padding: 10px 15px 20px 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

`.loginPageHeader`, `.loginPageSignInForm`, and `loginPageFooter` are inside `.loginPage` 
The header and the footer are kinda huge when the browser is smaller and the `signin` form is not aligned in the center.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxXKn.png)

```
<div className="loginPage">
                <div className="loginPageHeader col-lg-12">
                    <div className="floatleft secservices">
                        <img src={require('../../images/some-image.png')}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="loginContainer"></div>
                <div className="loginPageSignInForm">
                    <h2 className="form-signin-heading">Log in to Home</h2>
                    {errorLogin}
                    <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={this.formSubmit}>
                        <input onChange={this.setEmail} type="email" className="login-form-control"
                            autoComplete="email" placeholder="Email" required></input>
                        <input onChange={this.setPass} type="password" className="login-form-control"
                            autoComplete="new-password" placeholder="Password" required></input>
                        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
                            type="submit">Log In</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <LoginPageFooter />
            </div>
```

LoginPageFooter component:

```
return (
            <div id="loginPageFooter">
                <div className="col-lg-4">
                    <div id="loginPageFooterText">
                        sdafadsfdsfasf
                    </div>
                    <div className="loginPageLinks">
                        <a className="footerLink"></a>
                        <a className="footerLink"></a>

                        <a className="footerLink"
                            >Y</a>
                        <a className="footerLink"></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-5"></div>
                <div className="col-lg-3" style={styles.textAlignRight}>
                    <div id="contactSupport">NEED HELP? </div>
                    <div><a href="j.html"
                        title="Contacts &amp; Procedures">Customer Support</a>
                            : 1-444444444</div>
                    <div><a href="mailto:2342314@sdafsd.com"
                        title="&amp; Procedures">Email</a>
                            : 2342314@sdafsd.comm</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
```

Comment: where is your HTML? How can we help you without the code you are using?

Comment: please provide full content of your problem

Comment: @DanieleFois done

Comment: @JoseAPL added.

Comment: According to your CSS your `.loginPage` is `static` i.e. it has `position: static;` your `#loginPageFooter` has `position: absolute;` i.e. it is not placed inside `.loginPage` but inside HTML element. Moreover, you've added `z-index: 3;` to your `.loginPageHeader` which has `position: static;` by default so `z-index` won't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use vh attributes. It means viewport height and is a percentage. So height: 90vh would mean 90% of the viewport height. This works in most modern browsers.

Eg.

```
div {
  height: 90vh;
}
```

You can forego the rest of your silly 100% stuff on the body.

If you have a header you can also do some fun things like take it into account by using the calc function in CSS.

Eg.

```
div {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

This will give you 100% of the viewport height, minus 50px for your header.

Hope it helped!

Comment: put those dimensions where exactly ? I do have `100vh` in `body`

Comment: then put vh in the header and footer but instead use what ever percent and then use 100vw

Comment: also try max-height: 100vh;